# Getting "Solver stopped prematurely" error while using lsqcurvefit for optimizing two coefficients at the same time (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to optimize 2 last coefficients (g(1) and g(2)) of my equations but I only have few data to fit to them. I also don't know a good start for initial value of coefficients for the solver.
Before, I wrote the equations in a way that it only had g(1), lsqcurevfit solved it and optimized g(1) to 9.9 *10^10, After that I checked the equations and understood that I also need to add g(2) to it but now I can't optimize them together ant fit the equations to the data I have.

Here is my code:

file 1:

```
clc
t = [0, 23, 0, 23]; %I had 2 sets of data for time 0 to 23 and I used both
global y
global V
y = [0.085, 0.6, 0.995, 0.812];
b0=[100000, 1];
[X,RESNORM]=lsqcurvefit(@diff_g,b0,t,y,[],[])
```

file 2:

```
function V = diff_g(x,xdata)
global g
global y
g=x;
global V
s=[0.085;0.915;0;325000;0]*5*10^4;
z=ode45(@gfinder2,[0 23],s);
v1=interp1(z.x,z.y(1,:),xdata(1:2));
v2=interp1(z.x,z.y(2,:),xdata(1:2));
v=[v1./(v1+v2)];
j=[0.995;005;0;325000;0]*5*10^4;
z=ode45(@gfinder2,[0 23],j);
v1=interp1(z.x,z.y(1,:),xdata(3:4));
v2=interp1(z.x,z.y(2,:),xdata(3:4));
v3=[v1./(v1+v2)];
V=[v,v3];
end
```

file 3:

```
function dp = gfinder2(t,p)
dp = zeros(5,1);
a1=0.7540; 
C_max = 10^10;
landa = 0.1;
gamma = 0.2;
C_tot = p(1)+p(2);
s = 1.3 * 10^4;
epsilon=  0.98;
%r=10^10*9.9; g1
%alpha=1; g2
global g                            
dp(1) = a1*p(1)*(1-(p(1)+p(2))/C_max)-(landa*p(1))+(gamma*p(2))- epsilon*p(1)*(p(5)+g(2)*p(2))/(p(5)+g(2)*p(2)+g(1))-0.16*10^(-6)*p(4)*p(1);
dp(2) = a1*p(2)* (1-(p(1)+p(2))/C_max) - (gamma*p(2)) + (landa*p(1))+ epsilon*p(1)*(p(5)+g(2)*p(2))/(p(5)+g(2)*p(2)+g(1))-(0.16*10^(-6)*p(4)*p(2));
% no need for dp(3) because its empty
dp(4) = s + (p(4) * 12 * 10^(-2) * (C_tot^2/((2.02 * 10^(7))+(C_tot^2)))) - (4.12 * 10^(-2) * p(4)) - (4.5 * 10^(-8)* p(5)* p(4));
dp(5) = (2.2 * 10^(-1) * C_tot) - (0.35 * p(5));
end
```